# Make only one checkbox mutually exclusive in html

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am looking to create a list of checkboxes that a user can select and at the bottom of the list a separate checkbox that is labeled as none so that when a user selects that checkbox, all the other checkboxes are unticked. Additionally, when the none checkbox is selected and one of the other options is selected, the none checkbox gets deselected.

Comment: you should use radio button instead of checkbox. make radio button looks like checkbox if you want.

Comment: But radio buttons wouldn't allow for users to select multiple things

Comment: I think you should use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly straightforward; add `change` events to everything and just uncheck as necessary

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll(".option")
var none = document.querySelector(".none")

cbs.forEach(cb => {
   cb.addEventListener("change", () => {
      if(cb.checked)
         none.checked = false
   })
})

none.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if(none.checked) {
    cbs.forEach(cb => cb.checked = false);
  }
})
```

```html
<div><input type="checkbox" class="option">1</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" class="option">2</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" class="option">3</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" class="option">4</div>
<hr>
<div><input type="checkbox" class="none">none</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this way..

```js
myForm.oninput = e => {
  if (e.target === myForm.none && myForm.none.checked )
    myForm.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(r=>r.checked=false) 
  else if (e.target.matches('input[type=radio]') && e.target.checked)
    myForm.none.checked = false 
  }
```

demo:

```js
const myForm = document.forms['my-form']

myForm.oninput = e =>
  {
  if (e.target === myForm.none && myForm.none.checked )
    {
    myForm.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(r=>r.checked=false) 
    }
  else if (e.target.matches('input[type=radio]') && e.target.checked)
    {
    myForm.none.checked = false 
    }
  }
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault() // disable submit (page reload)
  console.clear()
  let formInputs = Object.fromEntries( new FormData(myForm).entries() ) 
  console.log( formInputs )
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Helvetica, Arial sans-serif;
  font-size   : 12px;
  }
form { width : 22em; }
fieldset { margin: .7em;}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top:0; left:50% !important; width:50%; }
.as-console-row         { background-color: yellow; }
.as-console-row::after  { display:none !important; }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="none"> none </label>
   <fieldset>
    <legend>group A</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioA" value="a1"> A 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioA" value="a2"> A 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioA" value="a3"> A 3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioA" value="a4"> A 4</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>group B</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioB" value="b1"> B 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioB" value="b2"> B 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioB" value="b3"> B 3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioB" value="b4"> B 4</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>group C</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioC" value="c1"> C 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioC" value="c2"> C 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioC" value="c3"> C 3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioC" value="c4"> C 4</label>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```